# Outlook Calendar Reminder

Tags: gratis, windows-7, calendar

I have not attended some meetings, because I closed Outlook for the following reasons:

- It needs much RAM (virtual memory, to be precise, might not be so much physical RAM)
- It appears in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list
- It appears in the task bar and uses space there

In order to not miss meetings in the future I want a tool like this:

- An application which notifies me about calendar events (not emails)
- Small memory footprint
- Tray icon so that it does not appear in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list
- Balloon notification or similar on due dates (note that I will probably hide the icon itself)
- Windows 7 x64
- Can have an Outlook plugin (32 Bit) for synchronizing the entries if needed
- Commercial use
- Gratis / donation preferred, up to 10 € acceptable

I don't want:

- Smartphone synchronization
- Anything which copies data into the cloud/Internet or somewhere else
- Email notification (if it has that feature it must be possible to turn it off)

I have tried:

- OWANotify - does not support calendar reminders (yet - it's on the wish list)
- Googling for "Outlook calendar reminder tray". But everything seems to be about email notification.

Comment: Check out [OWAtray](www.owatray.com).  I don't have any direct experience with it, but it looks like it might do what you want.

Comment: @Notre1: I can't figure out how to enter the correct URL. It's disabled. When I press start it says "Already connected", but the tray icon says "not connected". From the settings it seems I can disable calendar notification but not email notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to downvote this answer because it does not fulfill some of your requirements, but this is the way how I solved similar problem last year and I'm quite happy with it:

I decided to go online and take [Exchange Online Plan 1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/microsoft-exchange-online-compare-exchange-online-plans-try-or-buy-FX103764022.aspx). It is paid service $4/month and works like this:

[image]

(**green**=at Microsoft; **blue**=clients you are using)

So for most of the time I can have have my Outlook client (and even laptop) switched off and my mobile device (with **Outlook Mobile**, but iPhone etc. support Exchange, too) delivers me all my reminders and e-mails.

**Outlook WebApp** is a compromise between the two: almost full Outlook client is open inside the web page. (OWA should NOT to be confused with **Outlook.com** which has only basic functionalities.) It also plays notification sounds and has no taskbar button (because it is open in one of browser tabs).

The advantage is **all 3 clients work independently**, no connection between PC and mobile phone is needed. All the messaging takes up to 30 seconds. (Typically 10 seconds.)

Example: e-mail arrives to my mobile phone immediately after it was received by Exchange. Mobile phone is not checking server for e-mails (POP3, IMAP protocols), but Exchange server is actively notifying mobile phone when e-mail arrived (Push Mail – Exchange protocol).

If I update contact in mobile phone, in short time I find it updated in my desktop Outlook and vice versa.

If I'm without my laptop, I have full outlook at hand through Outlook WebApp.

For me this solution is definitely worth the money.

Mailbox size is 25 GB.

At my webhosting provider, I have redirected e-mails from my domain to Microsoft, but it works also without that: mailboxes have address **name@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com**.
But after redirection of my own domain, **name@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com** and **name@mycompany.com** represent the same mailbox.

One more thing: technical support is included, so if connections stopped working etc. I got a call from Microsoft tech support representative (within 1-2 hours after reporting) working with me on the problem.

As a bonus you get access to some Exchange-only features like:

- e-mail Out-of-office assistant (sends Out-of-office replies)
- server-side Outlook rules – these rules work on server, so for example to sort some e-mails into folders or to delete them you do not need to start your Outlook. After starting Outlook you only find these actions are already done.
- e-mail retention policies – for example spam is assigned 90-days retention policy, all such messages are automatically deleted after 90 days
- remote deletion of your mobile device content – from administrative interface you can send "delete all data" command to your lost mobile device
- after you lose your Outlook storage or break entire laptop, you simply install Outlook again and all Outlook data are shortly back (including settings like rules etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [OotD](http://www.outlookonthedesktop.com) (but I think it uses the actual Outlook application, in which case it will probably use the same amount of resources) or [DeskTask](http://www.carthagosoft.net/DeskTask.php). I haven't used any of them myself, so I can't give you any feedback on how they actually behave or any insights into their usability.